# Windows Authentication Encoding

Tags: .net, wcf, authentication, fiddler

When I use basic authentication; the credentials are passed in the HTTP header as a Base64 string as shown below (I have rubbed out the base 64 encoded password):

[image]

I can open the Text Wizard tool in Fiddler and paste in the base64 encoded data and it will tell me the username and password.

How does this work for Windows authentication.  For example, please see the screenshot below (again I have rubbed out the password):

[image]

How is the Windows username and password passed to the server?

The reason I ask is because I have an Intranet app that will be pen tested in a few months and I want to make sure there are no vulnerabilities.

Comment: See the code in http://stackoverflow.com/a/38009425/546871 for an example of how basic authentication headers can be generated. The code is not for Fiddler, but it may give the information you need.